# How to run .exe file multiple times using .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have one .exe file in my windows.
I need to run that file multiple times using batch file.

Could anyone please help me in this please?

Regards,
Manu

Comment: By "run multiple times", do you mean sequentially or in parallel ?

Comment: And how many times does the exe need to run?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
    your_program.exe
)
```

This will run the program 10 times (iterating through the loop, %i goes from 1 to 10).